# Symbolic link picking up wrong directory

Tags: rhel, symlink

Can anyone explain why this script is trying to create the wrong symbolic link?

The main issue is with the line:

```
ln -s ${src}/${lib} ${dest64}/${lib}
```

as it's throwing the following error:

```
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so/libpgtypes.so': File exists
```

but based on the echo messages the actual variable/link should be

```
/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so
```

This is the output from executing the script:

```
[root@server dir]# sh myscript.sh
Symbolic link already created from /opt/rh/rh-postgresql94/root/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so to /usr/lib/libpgtypes.so

ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql94/root/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so /usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so/libpgtypes.so`: File exists
Created symbolic link from /opt/rh/rh-postgresql94/root/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so to /usr/lib/libpgtypes.so
```

And this is the code in the script:
    #!/bin/bash

```
libraries=('libpgtypes.so')

src="/opt/rh/rh-postgresql94/root/usr/lib64"
dest="/usr/lib"
dest64="/usr/lib64"

for lib in ${libraries[*]}; do
    if [ -f ${dest}/${lib} ]; then
        echo "Symbolic link already created from ${src}/${lib} to ${dest}/${lib}"
    else
        ln -s ${src}/${lib} ${dest}/${lib}
        echo "Created symbolic link from ${src}/${lib} to ${dest}/${lib}"
    fi

    if [ -f ${dest64}/${lib} ]; then
        echo "Symbolic link already create from ${src}/${lib} to ${dest64}/${lib}"
    else
        echo "ln -s ${src}/${lib} ${dest64}/${lib}"
        ln -s ${src}/${lib} ${dest64}/${lib}
        echo "Created symbolic link from ${src}/${lib} to ${dest}/${lib}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so` is a directory on your system. (I can't tell you if that's right or wrong.)

---

Incidentally, as a matter of good coding practice I would strong recommend that you double-quote all your variables.

Instead of `ln -s ${src}/${lib} ${dest64}/${lib}` you should write `ln -s "${src}/${lib}" "${dest64}/${lib}"`. This will also allow you to handle your `for` loop correctly: `for lib in "${libraries[@]}"; do ... done` (notice `@` instead of `*`)

Comment: Ah! It seems there is a directory there already.....

Answer (score 1):

Use `-h` to check if dest is a symbolic link, for example you could remove all other types with:

```
if ! [ -h "${dest}/${lib}" ]; then
    rm -rf "${dest}/${lib}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be `/usr/lib64/libpgtypes.so` directory in that path. Please remove or rename it and execute the script again to avoid the error.